# ArcGIS automatically converting Z units when no Vertical CRS is defined

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry, z-value, vertical-transformation

I have seen this on several tools, but it was most obvious to me when using calculate geometry in the attribute table.

I have a point dataset that has Z values, but no VCS defined.  I then used calculate geometry to add those values to the attribute table.  In one sample point the calculate geometry in the attribute table was -4.279431.  When I pull the z value directly from the SHAPE geometry, I get -14.04009.  So it is obvious it is applying a feet to meters conversion.  I know Esri has been integrating VCS into the software for a few versions and I realize if I define my VCS I shouldn't have this problem (confirmed, I don't).

My question is, why the feet to meters conversion?  Can this be defined or turned off somewhere?

ArcGIS 10.7.1

Comment: Sounds unlikely,  because z value might represent anything, for example radio signal strength.

Comment: What sound unlikely?  Seems to me esri should leave values alone and not make any assumptions.  I keep seeing it, and maybe it something with my system, because i haven't found any commentary or issues about it.  If it's a 'feature' or a bug, i cant be the only one, unless it really is just me.

Comment: Unlikely that there is conversion of units happening behind the scene. Perhaps share a point or two so others can confirm this.